# Unimplemented type list when trying to write.table

Tags: r, dataframe, write.table

I have the following data.table (data.frame) called output:

```
> head(output)
        Id                                           Title IsProhibited
1 10000074                             Renault Logan, 2005            0
2 10000124              Ñêëàäñêîå ïîìåùåíèå, 345 ì<U+00B2>            0
3 10000175                                          Ñó-øåô            0
4 10000196             3-ê êâàðòèðà, 64 ì<U+00B2>, 3/5 ýò.            0
5 10000387        Samsung galaxy S4 mini GT-I9190 (÷¸ðíûé)            0
6 10000395 Êàðòèíà ""Êðûì. Ïîñåëîê Àðîìàò"" (õîëñò, ìàñëî)            0
```

I am trying to export it to a CSV like so:

```
> write.table(output, 'output.csv', sep = ',', row.names = FALSE, append = T)
```

However, when doing so I get the following error:

```
Error in .External2(C_writetable, x, file, nrow(x), p, rnames, sep, eol,  : 
unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'
In addition: Warning message:
In write.table(output, "output.csv", sep = ",", row.names = FALSE,  :
  appending column names to file
```

I have tried converting the `Title` to a string so that it is no longer of type `list` like so:

```
toString(output$Title)
```

But, I get the same error.  My types are:

```
> class(output)
[1] "data.frame"
> class(output$Id)
[1] "integer"
> class(output$Title)
[1] "list"
> class(output$IsProhibited)
[1] "factor"
```

Can anyone tell me how I can export my data.frame to CSV?

Another strange thing that I've noticed, is that if I write `head(output)` my text is not encoded properly (as shown above) whereas if I simply write `output$Title[0:3]` it will display the text correctly like so:

```
> output$Title[0:3]
[[1]]
[1] "Renault Logan, 2005"

[[2]]
[1] "Складское помещение, 345 м²"

[[3]]
[1] "Су-шеф"
```

Any ideas regarding that?  Is it relevant to my initial problem?

**Edit:** Here is my new output:

```
Id  Title   IsProhibited    
10000074    Renault Logan, 2005 0   
10000124    Ð¡ÐºÐ»Ð°Ð´ÑÐºÐ¾Ðµ Ð¿Ð¾Ð¼ÐµÑ‰ÐµÐ½Ð¸Ðµ, 345 Ð¼<U+00B2>    0   
10000175    Ð¡Ñƒ-ÑˆÐµÑ„ 0   
10000196    3-Ðº ÐºÐ²Ð°Ñ€Ñ‚Ð¸Ñ€Ð°, 64 Ð¼<U+00B2>, 3/5 ÑÑ‚.  0   
10000387    Samsung galaxy S4 mini GT-I9190 (Ñ‡Ñ‘Ñ€Ð½Ñ‹Ð¹)  0   
10000395    ÐšÐ°Ñ€Ñ‚Ð¸Ð½Ð° \\"ÐšÑ€Ñ‹Ð¼. ÐŸÐ¾ÑÐµÐ»Ð¾Ðº ÐÑ€Ð¾Ð¼Ð°Ñ‚\"\" (Ñ…Ð¾Ð»ÑÑ‚     Ð¼Ð°ÑÐ»Ð¾)"    0
10000594    ÐšÐ°Ð»ÑŒÑÐ½ 25 ÑÐ¼  0   
10000612    1-Ðº ÐºÐ²Ð°Ñ€Ñ‚Ð¸Ñ€Ð°, 45 Ð¼<U+00B2>, 6/17 ÑÑ‚. 0   
10000816    Ð“Ð°Ñ€Ð°Ð¶, 18 Ð¼<U+00B2>   0   
10000831    ÐŸÐ»Ð°Ñ‚ÑŒÐµ    0   
10000930    ÐšÐ°Ñ€Ð±ÑŽÑ€Ð°Ñ‚Ð¾Ñ€Ñ‹ Ðš-22Ð˜, Ðš-22Ð“ Ð¾Ñ‚ Ð³Ð°Ð· 21 Ð¸ Ð³Ð°Ð· 51 0
```

Notice how line ID 10000395 is messed up?  It seems to contains quotes of it's own which are messing up the CSV.  How can I fix that?

Comment: Flatten the `list` column with `paste` and try again.

Comment: Looks like `unlist(output)` may be an option, too.

Comment: I don't see `unlist` as an option here. You can `unlist` and expand those values to separate new rows, duplicating all of the other columns as required.

Comment: Hmm you're right, unlist isn't working.  Can you please provide an example how to flatten the list column with paste?  I am not familiar with that approach. I have also tried `sapply(output$Title, FUN = paste)`

Comment: Dumb question...but are you actually putting the result of `toString(output$Title)` back into `output$Title`, like `output$Title <- toString(output$Title)`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you should be able to do something like this (untested) to get "flatten" your `list` into a character vector:

```
output$Title <- vapply(output$Title, paste, collapse = ", ", character(1L))
```

As also mentioned, if you wanted to try the `unlist` approach, you could "expand" each row by the individual values in `output$Title`, something like this:

```
x <- vapply(output$Title, length, 1L)          ## How many items per list element
output <- output[rep(rownames(output), x), ]   ## Expand the data frame
output$Title <- unlist(output$Title, use.names = FALSE)  ## Replace with raw values
```

Comment: I am not sure how to explain the results - basically, they are unexpected.  When I output to CSV, it creates like 100+ columns (I only expect 3 columns).  Also, if I do `head(output)` it outputs a lot of data (almost freezes RStudio).

Comment: @user1477388, Oops. I meant `vapply` not `do.call`. This is why you should always post a minimal reproducible example!

Comment: @user1477388, `vapply` is like your `sapply` approach, which should also work if you add the `collapse = ", "` part to it.

Comment: Thanks this seems to work well enough.  The only strange thing is that it doesn't output my Russian text (the encoding is all messed up, as described in my question above).  I am even setting the encoding in code like `write.table(output, 'output.csv', sep = ',', row.names = FALSE, append = T, fileEncoding = 'UTF-8')`

Comment: Do you think I should open a new question regarding the messed up `write.csv` output?

Comment: @user1477388, if you do, please use `dput(head(output))` so that others can see exactly what you're working with.

Answer (score 78):

Do this, irrespective of how many columns you have:

```
df <- apply(df,2,as.character)
```

Then do `write.csv`.

Comment: Why does this help?  What is happening and how does this fix it?

Comment: This works because it's coercing all of the columns in the data frame to character. The issue is that one of this columns in data frame is stored as a list, which can't be written in a tabular format (or not by default). Setting everything to character "solves" that though it may be introducing unexpected issues and you should really try to figure out why one of the columns is a list in the first place.

Answer (score 24):

There is a new function (introduced in november 2016) in data.table package that handles writing a data.table object to csv quite well, even in those cases when a column of the data.table is a list.

```
fwrite(data.table, file ="myDT.csv")
```

Comment: this gives me the error: 
`Error in fwrite(DT, file = "myDT.csv") : 
  Row 1 of list column is type 'list' - not yet implemented. fwrite() can write list columns containing atomic vectors of type logical, integer, integer64, double, character and factor, currently.`

Comment: So you have a list inside a list inside a `data.frame`. Convert your column to a something easier to convert to a data.frame!

Comment: @llrs How would I do that? I'm having trouble with it here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59996500/how-do-i-remove-list-columns-without-removing-columns-derived-from-list-columns?noredirect=1#comment106123337_59996500

Answer (score 11):

Another easy solution. Maybe one or more columns are of type `list`, so we need convert them to "character" or data frame. So there are two easy solutions

1. Convert each column "as.character" using--

   `df$col1 = as.character(df$col1)`

   `df$col2 = as.character(df$col2)`

   .......and so on
2. The best one convert `df` in to a "matrix"

   `df = as.matrix(df)`

now write `df` into csv.  Works for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
# First coerce the data.frame to all-character
df = data.frame(lapply(output, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# write file
write.csv(df,"output.csv")
```

Answer (score 1):

Those are all elegant solutions.

For the curious reader who would prefer some R-code to ready made packages , here's an R-function that returns a non-list dataframe that can be exported and saved as .csv.

output is the "troublesome" data frame in question.

```
df_unlist<-function(df){

df<-as.data.frame(df)

nr<-nrow(df)

c.names<-colnames(df)

lscols<-as.vector(which(apply(df,2,is.list)==TRUE))

if(length(lscols)!=0){

for(i in lscols){

temp<-as.vector(unlist(df[,i]))

if(length(temp)!=nr){

adj<-nr-length(temp)

temp<-c(rep(0,adj),temp)

}

df[,i]<-temp

} #end for

df<-as.data.frame(df)

colnames(df)<-c.names
}
return(df)
}
```

Apply the function on dataframe "output" :

```
newDF<-df_unlist(output)
```

You can next confirm that the new (newDF) data frame is not 'listed' via apply(). This should successfully return FALSE.

```
apply(newDF,2,is.list)         #2 for column-wise step.
```

Proceed to save the new dataframe, newDF as a .csv file to a path of your choice.

```
write.csv(newDF,"E:/Data/newDF.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

- the path you want to save to is `Path`, i.e. `path=Path`
- `df` is the dataframe you want to save,

follow those steps:

1. Save `df` as *txt* document:

   ```
   write.table(df,"Path/df.txt",sep="|")
   ```
2. Read the text file into R:

   ```
   Data = read.table("Path/df.txt",sep="|")
   ```
3. Now save as *csv*:

   ```
   write.csv(Data, "Path/df.csv")
   ```

That's it.

Comment: 1. still gives me the error: `Error in write.table(df, "df.txt", sep = "|") : 
  unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'`