# Can someone explain the error i am receiving when using write.csv

Tags: r

I have tried googling this error I received when trying to save data frame as csv and I can not find anything on it.

```
 write.csv(flights2, "low_energy_analysis_table.csv")
```

> Error in write.table(flights2, "low_energy_analysis_table.csv", col.names = NA,  : 
>     unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'

I imported data (flights) and added new columns to the data and saved it as flights2.

orginal data is 288 obs of 135 variables
variables are a mix of:  date, num, factor, char
ran the class function, returns as a data frame

```
> class(flights)
[1] "spec_tbl_df" "tbl_df"      "tbl"         "data.frame"
```

new table is 
data frame is 288 obs of 261 variables
variables are a mix of:  date, num, factor, char
ran the class function, returns as a data frame

```
> class(flights2)
[1] "data.frame"
```

Not sure of why it won't allow me to save the new table.

```
write.csv(flights2, "low_energy_analysis_table.csv")
```

> Error in write.table(flights2, "low_energy_analysis_table.csv", col.names = NA,  : 
>     unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'

What does this error mean?

Expected it to save the new table not give an error message

Comment: It may be because you have a `list` column in the dataset.  Please check the `str(flights2)`

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24829027/unimplemented-type-list-when-trying-to-write-table

Comment: thanks, i tried that and it didnt list anything as a list, i did isolate the problem to the last bit of my code by removing sections and i found the last section was causing the issue, but i have no idea why.